# Weird Behavior between IIS and SignalR

Tags: asp.net, iis, signalr

Ok I hope i can explain this well. In visual studio, i used signalrV2 to try to make a textarea update all the other clients textarea as well.

```
$("#ta").bind("input copy paste", function () {
                hubProxy.server.update($("#ta").val());
            });
```

Meaning if i type "ABC" in one textarea, all the other browsers textarea contains "ABC". I have already done this in visual studio and its working even if i open 10 tabs, all 10 tabs are synchronised.

But the moment i publish it to IIS, heres what happens. I open 3 tabs. In the 1st tab i type "abc", only the 2nd tab gets updated. The moment i close the first tab, that is when the third tab's textarea gets updated with "abc".

So my problem is that why are only a max of 2 tabs working together to update each other at any one time in IIS?

EDIT:
Then i tried with 2 hand phones and a PC. Same problem. Only one hand phone and a PC can sync with each other. The moment i close my PC tab. Both phones synced with each other. How do i solve this? This cant be a browser limit right? I am using 3 different devices. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: What version of IIS is this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SignalR and Browser Connection limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724202/signalr-and-browser-connection-limit)

Comment: its a browser limitation https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/849

Comment: Then i tried with 2 hand phones and a PC. Same problem. Only one hand phone and a PC can sync with each other. The moment i close my PC tab. Both phones synced with each other. How do i solve this? This cant be a browser limit right? I am using 3 different devices. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: After reading your question, I tried with my own chat app.   The client side is the index.html with JavaScript which can be run using any desktop or mobile browser.  I placed this html in the iis.  the signalr Server side is a winform written in c#.  since i use cordova to develop this app, the index.html also can be put inside an Android or iPhone to run as a native app.

Comment: then I open 3 Android phone native client, 1 Android chrome browser, 1 pc desktop chrome browser and 1 pc desktop ie browser(total 6 clients) and click send message button in 1 client, all 6 clients get the message simultaneously.  without your problem!

Comment: try to give you more information.  I'm using visual studio 2015 Community RC with cordova 4.3.0 to develop this chat app.  the iis Server is a Windows Server 2012 Standard Edition.